# How to trim the URL in a Master Page in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page

I'm trying to figure out how to get a portion of the url in a Master Page in SharePoint 2016 on-prem.  For example, I have several site collections that look like this:

http://mainsite.domain.com/sites/test1/...
http://mainsite.domain.com/sites/test2/...

In a master page, how do I trim off everything after the .com to end up with a url that looks like this:

http://mainsite.domain.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Actually,** I don't know why you need to get only the `hostname` in your master page as well as you don't specify where exactly you will use it.

But as per your request, if you need to just get the hostname, try to use the below JS code

```
var hostname= window.location.hostname;
console.log(hostname);
```

I suggest to try it first in the **console (F12)** to make sure that exactly what you need!

Comment: Thank you for your help.  That answered my question.  Also found this link to be handy with even more about window.location   http://www.surfingsuccess.com/javascript/javascript-window-location-object-properties.html#.XGrI7PZFy70